# Impossible to access OVH API from Symfony command online

Tags: php, api, symfony, ovh

Here is my problem: I'm developing a Symfony project which accesses telephony and email data from OVH API. Since I'm working in local, I've never met any problems, the API connection was working and I could recover all data.

Yesterday I deployed my project online on an OVH hosting, and when I launch a command from the SSH panel, I get cURL error 7.

The problem doesn't come from the API because I call it in my Controller and I don't get any errors.

My command is :

```
(php/5.6/production/) ~/www $ php bin/console converseo:updateTelephony
```

And the error I get :

```
[GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException]
  cURL error 7: Failed to connect to 213.186.33.117: Network is unreachable (
  see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

I don't know why this command works on localhost and in my controller, but doesn't work online.

Comment: did you check if the server isn't undergoing any maintenance? http://status.ovh.com/

Comment: Yes, I call Ovh and they told me there is no probleme with the server, and as I say, I call the Api on my controller and it's actually working.. the problem really come from the command :(

Comment: in ssh, try to ping to the target server. there could be a firewall issue. Your firewall or ovh.

Comment: Indeed, I can't ping the Ovh Api Ip : `ping 213.186.33.117` and get `connect: Network is unreachable`. How can I solve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a similar problem in the past with SSH.

I resolved it by creating a CRON task in OVH admin menu. This CRON task call myfile.sh.

Myfile.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/yourpath
/usr/local/php5.6/bin/php bin/console converseo:updateTelephony
```

It was ok for me because I needed to execute the command only sometimes in the day. I hope it will helps you.

If you need to launch this command in a specific moment, I think you will need to upgrade your hosting account(vps for example) and type the command directly on the server.

Comment: Thanks ! I will try this. Just a question, did you put your "myfile.sh" in the www folder ?

Comment: Yes I did. 
In the .sh file your path have to be "/home/yourname/www/yourpath....". You can find it by doing a php realpath.
In the ovh cron menu, your path have to be "www/....". Choose "other langage", and don't forget to check "activate it".

Comment: I have a probleme understandig the placement of the files. Currently, I have a tree like that : **/home/myNameSite/www**. Where I'm supposed to put the myfile.sh ? And what about thtat ? : `cd /home/MyNameSite
/usr/local/php5.6/bin/php bin/console converseo:updateTelephony`

Comment: Place it wherever you want.

Comment: Okay, suppose thtat I put in on /home/myNameSite/www/myfile.sh. Does  `cd /home/MyNameSite` work ? And on the Ovh menu, what is the path after **./** ?

Comment: No. You have to put the complete path. So for you :
cd /home/MyNameSite/www  .
On ovh : 
www/yourfile

Comment: Okay I put that ! I tell you in one hour (I can't reduce the execution time in ovh...) the result :) Thanks !

Comment: Yes I know this "1 hour" thing ^^ .
A little tip: a cron task is one per hour,but you can create 20 same cron tasks. It will run at a random minute(the number before ****, for example 5**** means each hour at 01h05, 02h05 etc).

So you can launch your cron task each minute if you want, for testing ;).

Hopefully it will work!

Comment: Unfortunately, I get this error : `[2017-05-30 14:43:02] ## OVH ## START - 2017-05-30 14:43:02.253272 executing: /homez.93/MyNameSite/./www/test.sh 
[2017-05-30 14:43:02] No such file or directory` I don't know where is my path problem

Comment: I don't know why there is a **./** before **/www**, I thought that Ovh didn't take it..

Comment: It's not the problem. In my case I 've got : 
"## OVH ## START - 2017-05-30 16:06:03.295628 executing: /homez.myNumber/mysite/./www/folder/folder/cronall.sh " .
And it works.

Comment: Are you sure your test.sh is on the folder www ?

Comment: Yes, my file is in **home/MySiteName/www/test.sh**, it contains **/usr/local/php5.6/bin/php bin/console converseo:updateTelephony** and in ovh, I put the path to **./www/test.sh**

Comment: And un get  :                                                                                      
`[2017-05-30 16:43:02] ## OVH ## START - 2017-05-30 16:43:02.115860 executing: /homez.93/converseca/./www/test.sh 
[2017-05-30 16:43:02] Exec format error
[2017-05-30 16:43:02] 
[2017-05-30 16:43:02] ## OVH ## END - 2017-05-30 16:43:02.259420 exitcode: 255`

Comment: Your file have to contain #!/bin/bash on the first line.

Try some different test to find the good ovh cron path. You can try with php file too (not necessarly the .sh).

Comment: Okay ! I think the path is good (cause of **Exec format error**) so I'll see with **#!/bin/bash** Thanks :)

Comment: Ok nice, this time it seems your cron task found your file. Should works.

Comment: Still not working.. it seems that the code is launching but get error : `[2017-05-30 17:07:01] ## OVH ## START - 2017-05-30 17:07:01.372266 executing: /homez.93/MyNameSite/www/test.sh 
[2017-05-30 17:07:01] No such file or directory
[2017-05-30 17:07:01] 
[2017-05-30 17:07:01] ## OVH ## END - 2017-05-30 17:07:01.455275 exitcode: 255`

Comment: Show me your sh file.

Comment: My sh files : `#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/php5.6/bin/php bin/console converseo:updateTelephony` My path is good cause I try with a Php files and my echo works fine

Comment: Did you manage it in 3 different lines like in my example ? Don't write everything in the same line.
Are you sure you use the good version of php ? 
Are you sure php is accessible with this path for you ?
Maybe you should ask on OVH forum, or OVH support team.

I can't help you more.
If you think my suggestion helped you, don't hesitate to vote ;) .
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by putting a PHP file into my www folder, which contains :

```
<?php
    shell_exec("sh myfile.sh");
?>
```

And `myfile.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /homez.myNumber/MyNameSite/www
/usr/local/php5.6/bin/php bin/console converseo:MyCommand --env=prod
```